# Xcode String Searching Algorithm

Tags: string, xcode, algorithm, string-search

How does Xcode's autocompletion algorithm work?

I am always amazed by how fast Xcode picks up the code blocks I want to write. I have looked at some different string matching algorithms but none seems to be working as the one Apple uses in Xcode. I would find it quite interesting what type of algorithm they are using.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Xcode Autocompletion]

The image above shows Xcode "predicting" that **UTV** should be **U**I**T**able**V**iew

Comment: Since no one outside Apple knows what Apple is doing, and no one inside Apple is allowed to tell you, the answer to the question "what type of algorithm they are using" would be a matter of opinion (or guesswork).

Answer (score 2):

It's not just a simple string searching algorithm. It uses nearest code to the scope, last code you picked with the same shortcut, precompiled codes, codes in frameworks, your own defined codes, and many other stuff sorted by some intelligent definition. Since it's private by apple, we may not know how exactly they achieve this. But this year, they open sourced their [LSP repository](https://github.com/apple/sourcekit-lsp) to bring support for these kind of stuff to other editors, even the VIM in terminal! You can investigate on that if you are interested.

Also there are some projects out there like [TabNine](https://tabnine.com) witch is the all-language autocompleter. It uses machine learning to provide responsive, reliable, and relevant suggestions trained with over 2million github repositories. You can check that out too if you are interested.

Who knows what exactly programming and tech lead companies are currently using while we are looking for algorithms? Maybe a lot of machine learnings is included and only machines knows the exact algorithms.